# Measuring the earth's electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, electric-current, earth

My question stems from a question on the Dutch VWO-level highschool state exam (from 1993) concerning a device to measure the earth's electric field. It consists of two plates positioned above one another, as shown in this image:

[image: Two perpendicular plates to measure the earth's electric field]

When the upper plate covers the lower plate, the charge that has built up on the lower plate will flow back to earth / ground, as it is no longer held by the electric field.

From a different perspective, the device looks like this:

[image: Upper plate is actually a disk with holes that will rotate over the lower plate]

The upper disk now starts to spin, periodically covering and uncovering the lower plate. As a charge builds up in / flows back to earth from the lower plate (depending on the position of the upper disk), a current flows through the Amp meter A. This current is used to determine the strength of the electric field. Here's a graph of the current:

[image: The current as measured by Amp meter A in time]

One of the questions on the exam was to plot this same graph (current I in time t) if the upper disk were to spin twice as fast. The answer is the following graph:

[image: Current in time if disk were to spin twice as fast]

The period is twice as short, and the current through the Amp meter is twice as high.

My question concerns this last aspect: Why is the current twice as high if the disk spins twice as fast? I would think that the current's magnitude would only depend on the strength of the electric field, not the rotation of the upper disk.

This has been bothering me for days, hopefully one of you can shine some light on this!

Comment: Are you sure that this is a real current Amp meter reading? Or is it just a picture to illustrate the effect?

Comment: According to the exam question, the current I is measured with an ideal ammeter. Also, the official answer specifically mentions the current being twice the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give an explanation following the logic of school teachers and examiners. The current is determined by the change in the electric charge of the bottom plate $I=k_1dq/dt$. The charge is determined by the electric field and the unshielded area of the bottom plate $q=k_2ES(t)$.The unshielded area $S(t)$ is a periodic function with a period $2\pi /\omega $, and in this case S is determined by the angle, which linearly depends on time as $\pm \omega t$.  Finally we find $I=\pm k\omega E$ is also a periodic function with a period $2\pi /\omega $. The constant $k$ depends on the geometry of the system. If we double the frequency, the amplitude of the current will double, and the period will be halved. To prove all this we need to create a 3D model of the device. I can create this model if the society supports me (at least they do not delete this answer).

Comment: Ah, so the current I is not proportional to the strength of the electric field itself, but to the rate of change at which the lower plate is 'exposed' to the electric field? Which is the rate of change of your S(t) ?

Comment: This is correct from the point of view of school teachers. In fact, there is an edge effect that needs to be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

The charge Q per cycle, independent of rotational speed, is directly proportional to the Electric field, of course, the greater the field the more charge Q is electrically induced on the moving vanes independent of speed,  the vanes are a capacitor of varying magnitude....greater when positioned directly over each other and since Q=CV  and E=V/D
Q=EVD  the greater the field the greater the charge  and thus the greater the current

Comment: There's a little typo in your answer. In the last line it should be $Q=ECD$ rather than $Q=EVD$. You can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting mathematical expressions.